# Drupal views & to do list

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, view

Wondered if anyone can tell me whether the following is possible within views.

I have installed To do module  - http://drupal.org/project/to_do
I then created my own view which lists all the tasks created in a particular Organic Group, which works lovely.

One of the **fields** ive added as the ***to do button field*** which gives the user the ability to mark a task as finshed from the view listing.

the problem I have is that all users part of that group can see that buton & has the ability to mark the task as finished.

Is there a way I can use views to only show that button if the current logged in user is the author of that node( to do task).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Views have different templates. In one of them all the fields are being printed. You could in that template make a check if the user is the author and then only print the todo field.

You cam click the theme information link inside the view to get a list of templates that's used and what you could call a custom template for views to use it.

Answer (score 0):

This will only show content the user created. It's a pretty simple argument

[image: User:UID Argument]